# Comparing the contents in the array

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I compare the values in the array to each other in ruby?

I would like to compare the values in the array to check the maximum value of the array.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to find the maximum? It's already been done.

```
[1, 5, 3].max # => 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby arrays (or anything that includes the Enumerable module) have a [`max` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```ruby
a = [20, 30, 100, 2, 3]
a.max # => 100
```

If you wanted to write your own for educational purposes, you could iterate over the array while retaining the largest value seen at each point:

```ruby
class Array
  def my_max
    max = nil # Default "max" to nil, since we haven't seen any values yet.
    self.each { |x| max = x if (!x || x>max) } # Update with bigger value(s).
    max # Return the max value discovered.
  end
end
```

Or, if you are interested in functional programming consider using the [Enumerable `reduce` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), which generalizes the process in the `my_max` version and uses the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) for brevity:

```ruby
class Array
  def my_max2
    self.reduce(nil) { |max,x| (!max || x>max) ? x : max }
  end
end
```

Comment: Your `my_max` implementation is too rocket science for a novice, I'm afraid. I would write it in longer form and add comments.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: yes, good point.  I've added a straightforward, annotated version in addition to the rocket science! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing integers, then

```
[1,3,2].max will do the work
```

if you are comparing integers that are stored in string format, try:

```
["1","3","2"].map(&:to_i).max
```

which will convert your string array into an int array first, and apply the max method

If you going to use such comparison often, I suggest you store the actual array in int format, so it actually saves you server some work times.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply invoke `max`

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.max # outputs 4
```

Also for minimum value you can do

```
a.min # outputs 1
```